# Pausing/turn off three.js TrackballControls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using `TrackballControls` to rotate the camera in my scene using the mouse but also need to be able to rotate individual objects in the scene using the mouse.  I'd like to be able to toggle on/off `TrackballControls` to accomplish this.  However, so far there are issues with everything I've tried.  This is how my controls are defined:

```
var controls; // global
```

inside `init()`:

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

and finally in `animate()`:

```
controls.update();
```

So far, I've tried:

1. **Removing the event listener** like this: `controls.removeEventListener( 'change', render );` which didn't change anything; `controls` worked the same as it always has.
2. **Conditionally updating the controls** like this:

(global)

```
var enableControls = true;
```

(in `animate`)

```
if (enableControls == true) {
    controls.update();
}
```

and then toggling `enableControls` using a `KeyDown` event.  This seemed to work, because when `enableControls` was false I could rotate an object without moving the camera.  However, when I `update` again, the camera moves significantly (it moves to where it would have been based on my clicking/dragging done while I wasn't updating).

I tried both of these separately and in conjunction with one another with no luck.

Comment: Try `controls.enabled = false;` Also, you likely do not need `controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );`

Comment: That works perfectly and I feel like an idiot.  Definitely post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable `TrackballControls`, all you need to do is set

```
controls.enabled = false;
```

Also, you likely do not need `controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );` since you are calling `controls.update()` in the animation loop.

three.js r.67

Comment: Additionally: I had the problem that after re-activating the controls, the scene would 'skip' (rotate) to the orientation where it should've been if controls were kept enabled. Solved this by calling `controls.saveState()` before disabling and `controls.reset()` before re-enabling controls. [using r.91]